# Why doesn't my loop run

Tags: c

I'm test running values by looping letters and numbers. However, only the number loop is run by some reason.

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int inuti(double x, double y, double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    int x_inuti;
    int y_inuti;

    if (x1 < x2)
        x_inuti = x > x1 && x < x2;
    else
        x_inuti = x > x2 && x < x1;
    if (y1 < y2)
        y_inuti = y > y1 && y < y2;
    else
        y_inuti = y > y2 && y < y1;
    return x_inuti && y_inuti;
}

int main(void) {
    double x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2;
    char text_x, text_y, text_x1, text_y1, text_x2, text_y2;
    int resultat;
    int i;



    char tecken[] = "abcdefgABCDEFG.+-";
    char teckenback[] = "-+.GFEDXBAgfedcba";
    int max;
    int maxback;
    max = strlen(tecken);
    maxback = strlen(teckenback);

    //These loops do only run if the number loops are commented.

    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        for (i = 0; i < maxback; i++) {
            for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                for (i = 0; i < maxback; i++) {
                    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
                        for (i = 0; i < maxback; i++) {




                            text_x = tecken[i];
                            text_y = teckenback[i];
                            text_x1 = tecken[i];
                            text_y1 = teckenback[i];
                            text_x2 = tecken[i];
                            text_y2 = teckenback[i];


                            printf("punktens x-varde: %c \n", text_x);


                            printf("punktens y-varde: %c \n", text_y);

                            printf("\n");

                            printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %c \n", text_x1);


                            printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %c \n", text_y1);

                            printf("\n");

                            printf("Andra hornets x-varde %c \n", text_x2);


                            printf("Andra hornets y-varde %c \n", text_y2);

                            printf("\n");

                            printf("##### Endast nummer tillatet! #####");
                            printf("\n");
                            printf("\n");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }




    for (x = 0; x <= 3; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y <= 3; y++) {
                for (x1 = 0; x1 <= 3; x1++) {
                    for (y1 = 0; y1 <= 3; y1++) {
                        for (x2 = 0; x2 <= 3; x2++) {
                            for (y2 = 0; y2 <= 3; y2++){

                                printf("punktens x-varde: %.1f \n", x);


                                printf("punktens y-varde: %.1f \n", y);

                                printf("\n");

                                printf("Ena hornets x-varde: %.1f \n", x1);


                                printf("Ena hornets y-varde: %.1f \n", y1);

                                printf("\n");

                                printf("Andra hornets x-varde %.1f \n", x2);


                                printf("Andra hornets y-varde %.1f \n", y2);

                                printf("\n");

                                resultat = inuti(x, y, x1, y1, x2, y2);


                                if (resultat == 1)
                                    printf("Punkten var inuti rektangeln.\n");
                                else
                                    printf("Punkten var utanfor rektangeln.\n");

                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");


                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

If I comment away the number loops, the letter loop runs normally but when I'm running the whole code, only the number loop is run. No error is given. Does anyone know why this occurs?
Thank you

Comment: Learn to use a debugger. It will make your life as a programmer vastly easier.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28311310/3933332 And the difference to this is?

Comment: Did you notice the difference between the two loops? In the first one you use always i for every loop, in the second one you use a different variable for each loop.

Comment: @Rizier123 different question.

Comment: @Steve I know that, but why don't both loops run?

Answer (score 0):

In the first looping section only the last loop will work if maxback is higher than max. In another case if maxback is lower by 1 from max than again it will end because after the last iteration you have reached the end of the above loop. In any other cases the last two loops will run indefinetly.

In short my answer is: because the first loop does not finish, the second loop will not run.